# Use MySql server function using Laravel DB::select and DB:row

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to use Mysql Server function into `Laravel DB::select()`. 
The function is for a clean string from HTML tags.

I thought I could use this:

```
$event->select('id', 'title', \DB::raw("fnStripTags('description') AS description"));
```

But it's not working for me.

The SQL function is:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END
```

Comment: And how it's not working?

Comment: It's returning me that the function is not defined, but it is.

Comment: If that's full function syntax, then you are missing `CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags`